# union type inference change between v1.7 and v1.8

Tags: typescript1.8

In snippet below TypeScript compiler v1.7 identifies x as C1 under third typeguard clause

```
class C1 { item: string }
class C2 { item: string[] }
class C3 { item: string }

function Foo(x: C1 | C2 | C3): string {
    if (x instanceof C1)
        return x.item;
    else if (x instanceof C2)
        return x.item[0];
    else if (x instanceof C3)
        //in v1.7 compiler thinks x is C1 
        //in v1.8 compiler thinks x is C2 
        return x.item;
}
```

V1.8 thinks of x as C2 under third typeguard therefore making compilation to fail.
Is it intended or bug?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the compiler *both in v1.7 and v1.8* even though the final result is different in them. The `(x instanceof C3)` type guard should make it `C3` in that block **period**. I'll log a bug.

Bug report : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7271